# Creating HTTP Signature for CyberSource integration

Tags: c#, cybersource

I'm trying to get my product to connect to CyberSource with C#, however I'm having trouble.

In short, I'm trying to reproduce the Java code [here](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/hosted_flex/0_4_0/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=custom_server_integration.html&single=true) and essentially translate it in `C#`.

I end up with different results than they do.

Things I have commented out I have also tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace encoder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string body = "{\n \"encryptionType\": \"RsaOaep\","
+"\n \"targetOrigin\": \"https://example.com\"\n}";
            Console.WriteLine(body);
            string _merchantId = "merchant";
            string keyID = "01dbbc88-0736-4d31-94ed-7b84579731b2";
            string secret = "SXQgaXMgc2hhcmVkIHNlY3JldA==";
            string url = "https://apitest.cybersource.com/flex/v1/keys";

            //HashAlgorithm digester = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
            //byte[] digest = digester.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
            //string value = string.Format("SHA-256={0}", System.Convert.ToBase64String(digest));

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] digest = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
            string value = string.Format("SHA-256={0}", System.Convert.ToBase64String(digest));

            Console.WriteLine("Digest: " + value);
            Console.ReadLine();
            string todaysDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'");
            //string todaysDate = "Mon, 01 Jan 2018 00:00:00 GMT";
            Console.WriteLine("Current Time: " + todaysDate);

            Dictionary<string, string> signedHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            signedHeaders.Add("host", "apitest.cybersource.com");
            signedHeaders.Add("date", todaysDate);
            signedHeaders.Add("(request-target)", "post /flex/va/keys/");
            signedHeaders.Add("digest", value);
            //signedHeaders.Add("digest", "SHA-256=fRDzptXm4RRRD3pC/eoIBoHShRzjRAf7Xkj18upMtI8=");
            //signedHeaders.Add("digest", "SHA-256=YljtibTei+du4xVIDxMr3HBsyLAEDuiYaag9TcU9jHA=");
            signedHeaders.Add("v-c-merchant-id", _merchantId);

            Console.WriteLine("Signed Headers: " + signedHeaders);
            Console.ReadLine();

            StringBuilder signatureString = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder headersString = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> s in signedHeaders)
            {
                signatureString.Append('\n').Append(s.Key).Append(": ").Append(s.Value);
                headersString.Append(' ').Append(s.Key);
            }
            signatureString.Remove(0, 1);
            headersString.Remove(0, 1);


            HMACSHA256 sha256HMAC = new HMACSHA256(System.Convert.FromBase64String(secret));
            sha256HMAC.Initialize();

            StringBuilder signature = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha256HMAC.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureString.ToString()));
            signature.Append("keyid=\"").Append(keyID)
                .Append("\", ").Append("algorithm=\"HmacSHA256\", ")
                .Append("headers=\"").Append(headersString).Append("\", ")
                .Append("digest: signature=\"").Append(System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)).Append("\"");

            Console.WriteLine("Signature: " + signature);
            Console.ReadLine();


            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            myHttpWebRequest.Headers["v-c-merchant-id"] = _merchantId;
            myHttpWebRequest.Host = "apitest.cybersource.com";
            //myHttpWebRequest.Headers["v-c-date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 30000;  //' 30 second timeout'
            myHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            myHttpWebRequest.Date = DateTime.Now;
            //myHttpWebRequest.Date = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            byte[] myBytes;
            using (Stream myOutputStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                myBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
                myOutputStream.Write(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);
                myOutputStream.Close();
            }

            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
            using (WebResponse myWebResponse = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream RecieveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                Encoding encode = Encoding.UTF8;
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(RecieveStream, encode);

                strResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + strResponse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

I should get a response back from CyberSource, but I keep getting a `401 unauthorized error`.

I also notice that the very first console.writeline gets a very different digest of `SHA-256=lJooQmwcasZC4okGe61dGdcdlE672vGi5x0D/vmcZx8=`. 
I should get `SHA-256=YljtibTei+du4xVIDxMr3HBsyLAEDuiYaag9TcU9jHA=`.

*UPDATE*

I should also add that we are unable to use the CyberSource SDK as we cannot use ILMerge to merge with our DLL.

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

If I'm too late to the game for the OP, I hope my response will be helpful to others who are facing a similar issue.  Although my sample is POSTing to the PAYMENT method, the same issue applies in that I could not get my Digest and Signature hashes in the request header to match the examples and thus getting nothing but a 401 Unauthorized response from CyberSource.

Simple answer is to use the "official" C# hashing functions that can found here: 
https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-gettingstarted/GenerateHeader/httpSignatureAuthentication.html#id191TE000FUI_id1925AC001Y4

Still, you may not get the same hash when you compare your code to your example unless the body payload of what you're comparing is minified and the body payload of your example is minified as well.  I suspect that this is due to the differences in the final hash when comparing hashes to the two message bodies that may have the same content but differ in indentations, spacing, line-breaks, etc..  One small extra space throws the final hash off. But I assure you it's irrelevant that your hash differs from the example you are comparing against as long as your code is hashing the message body correctly.  Since the Digest hash is most likely being used to verify that the body of the request has not been tempered with.

I have my working sample code here: https://github.com/sarn1/example-cybersource-csharp-api-rest and a detailed explanation link there.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet. I don't know what is wrong with your code, but here is pre-built CyberSource C# client that can be used to request a Flex key - https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-samples-csharp

Comment: This samples is very simple and not fully functional. I tried to use API to download reports and it didn't work. Also almost all logic related on internal logger, console and other things that don't need to be inside library. Because of this i created a form for main library and maybe can do some basic updates. Also it would be great to get source for CyberSource.Authorization library for .NET. Looks like all of them has bad design and implementation. I am very sad to see this in such big product, maybe even serious. Very strange... :(